# How does android know which of my contacts are using android & should get an android icon?

Tags: android, xmpp

Is this something hidden that google shares with its internal systems (gmail uses android icons as well) or is it just data that's sent inside the normal Jabber traffic, that other clients ignore?

Edit:

I'm referring to "How does android/gmail know when to associate these icons:"

[image: Android Avarar]

Instead of the default:

[image: Standard avatar]

Comment: I’m unsure what you mean, could you expand your question, maybe give an example? If you mean the contact photos: Android (or most contact apps) shows an Android-icon per default if you didn’t specify a custom contact icon.

Comment: Added visuals. Did not mean to be vague.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [XMPP specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3920) defines a [resource identifier](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3920#section-3.4) that clients can use to identify themselves. Clients connecting via Android usually have a resource identifier, that begins with `ANDROID`, so it’s easy to identify connected Android clients.

It depends on your client if you are able to see the resource identifier itself. For example I’m using Trillian to connect to Google Talk and other XMPP systems, and that one shows the client’s resource identifier in the contact list. In case multiple clients are connected to the same account, this also allows you to see which clients are connected (as each used identifier is shown).

Comment: Extra info explaining multiple accounts is a good touch. Thanks.

Comment: Please assume that your resources are completely opaque bags of bits.  If you assign semantic to your resources like this, there will come a point about 18 months in where you will wish that you used XEP-0115 (http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0115.html) instead, but then it will be too late.

Comment: @JoeHildebrand Care to explain what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

@poke asked for a little more regarding my comment.

The first way that people tend to do device identification is to encode the device name into the resource portion of the JIDs used by that device, such as `joe@example.com/MYCLIENT` or `joe@example.com/MYCLIENT_[random string]`, then do string matching on the resource.  This will appear to work for a while, until you need to write another client for a different device, at which point, you've probably encoded both *identity* of the client as well as the *features* of that client into the resource string, and stuff starts to get tough.

A much better solution is to use [XEP-0115](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0115.html).  Read the How-it-works section **very** carefully.  It is a confusing idea to most people the first time they read it.  Summary:

```
<presence from='romeo@montague.lit/orchard'>
  <c xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/caps' 
     hash='sha-1'
     node='http://code.google.com/p/exodus'
     ver='QgayPKawpkPSDYmwT/WM94uAlu0='/>
</presence>
```

When a contact sends presence, she adds a capabilities tag, which includes a node name, which is just a URI you make up that describes your client.  That URI can be used to select an icon, or there's another approach we'll get to.

Next, you ask the sender what that icky ver string means:

```
<iq from='juliet@capulet.lit/chamber' 
    id='disco1'
    to='romeo@montague.lit/orchard' 
    type='get'>
  <query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info'
         node='http://code.google.com/p/exodus#QgayPKawpkPSDYmwT/WM94uAlu0='/>
</iq>
```

And then you **CACHE** the result:

```
<iq from='romeo@montague.lit/orchard' 
    id='disco1'
    to='juliet@capulet.lit/chamber' 
    type='result'>
  <query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info'
         node='http://code.google.com/p/exodus#QgayPKawpkPSDYmwT/WM94uAlu0='>
    <identity category='client' name='Exodus 0.9.1' type='pc'/>
    <feature var='http://jabber.org/protocol/caps'/>
    <feature var='http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info'/>
    <feature var='http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items'/>
    <feature var='http://jabber.org/protocol/muc'/>
  </query>
</iq>
```

After doing some normalization, you can SHA1-hash that result, and ensure that the hash matches the icky ver string.  Now, anyone who gives you that hash, you know their capabilities.  If you need to specify non-standard capabilities, just make up your own URIs to describe them, and add a feature to your caps.

Finally, if you don't want to run around modifying all of your clients when you add a new client to your mix, you can include an extension in your caps that just specifies a URL for the client icon.  [XEP-0232](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0232.html) (which is deferred, but that can't stop you from using it if you want, and can be resurrected if someone got excited about it) suggests:

```
<iq from='juliet@capulet.lit/chamber'
    to='romeo@montague.lit/orchard'
    id='disco1'
    type='result'>
  <query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info'
         node='http://code.google.com/p/exodus#RnWHG/MCjSwxZCk+p2kuN7i9kzo='>
    <x xmlns='jabber:x:data' type='result'>
      <field var='FORM_TYPE' type='hidden'>
        <value>urn:xmpp:dataforms:softwareinfo</value>
      </field>
      <field var='icon'>
        <media xmlns='urn:xmpp:media-element'
               height='80'
               width='290'>
          <uri type='image/jpeg'>http://www.shakespeare.lit/clients/exodus.jpg</uri>
          <uri type='image/jpeg'>cid:sha1+f24030b8d91d233bac14777be5ab531ca3b9f102@bob.xmpp.org</uri>
        </media>
      </field>
    </x>
  </query>
</iq>
```